# Font color changes between desktop and mobile preview

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, email-studio

I'm using content builder in email studio.

I have a button where I have set the font color. When in Desktop preview, the button text color is correct. However, when I switch to Mobile preview, the button text is white.

It doesn't matter what color I select, it is always white when in Mobile preview mode.

Is this a UI bug of some kind? Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the html?

Comment: Are you using the button content block or a custom HTML created button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the 'button' content block in the UI and not something custom made, you will need to change the 'mobile styles' section on the template to make sure the button displays your new color.  Be aware this will overwrite all button colors upon going to mobile.

First you go to the 'Template' tab in the email Content Builder Screen

[image]

Then you need to navigate down this tab until you find 'Mobile Styles'

[image]

Then finally you go down until you find the 'button' section.  Here you will change the color to what you want the default mobile color to be.

[image]

Your other option, if you don't want to make the color change universal, is to go into the HTML for that button and add `!important` to the `color:#AAAAAA` (where the `#AAAAAA` is your hex color code.) css attribute for the button. This will overwrite the media query that would overwrite the button on mobile.

Comment: Do you know, are you then limited to only 1 color?  The problem is, I have 2 yellow buttons with black text and a black button with white text - but can only choose one color for the Mobile Button Styles.  I know that I can just add `!important` to the others and that's fine for mobile, but then the problem is that the outlook will throw any `!important` declarations out the window; so then I'm stuck with blue text links in outlook.  Is there any *graceful* workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the button global styles in the template HTML code or in the Design tab.